# How to add specific styles of an Angular Material component

Tags: angular, material-design

I am currently using **Angular Material** for my app, but some styles are overriding the styles of the template I am using. They are actually a lot of classes those who are being affected.

I am trying to just add the styles of the components I need. I personally need **BottomSheet** and **Dialog** components from this Angular Material.

I found out that you can add specific styles of **Angular Material** with their theming option in their documentation, but when I add the styles for **BottomSheet** and **Dialog** to my `styles.scss` files, I don't see anything because I don't have the styles for `cdk-overlay-container`, but I can't find the scss file with those styles to add them to my styles.scss files.

This is my code in the `styles.scss` file so far:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

$candy-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$candy-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);
$candy-app-theme:   mat-light-theme($candy-app-primary, $candy-app-accent);

@include mat-bottom-sheet-theme($candy-app-theme);
@include mat-dialog-theme($candy-app-theme);
```

Any ideas about how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who are facing the same problem, just trying to add a specific component that needs this `cdk-overlay-container` styles. You just need to add the scss file with this library, just add this to your `styles.scss`:

```
@import '~@angular/cdk/overlay-prebuilt.css';
```